# Mysql Left join index

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I used the following query

```
select a.*,b.* from firsttable a left join secondtable b on a.id=b.item_id ORDER BY a.id DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

To display items from two tables, where the id of the first table is the item_id of the second. My question is , when I try to display this in php , if I want to display a.id i can try with:

```
while($row=$go->fetch_assoc()){
echo $row['id'];
}
```

or

```
while($row=$go->fetch_assoc()){
echo $row['a.id'];
}
```

since both tables have id,on the first example displays only if there are matching rows from first and second table and displays the id of second table, I want the id of first

and on the second it says undefined index.
Can you explain why is this please?

Edit:
Adding tables for example

```
id
info
username

id
item.id
username
```

Comment: run your query in phpmyadmin and see what the result is. every column has ti have its own name and this you can adress

Comment: Don't use `SELECT *`. Instead name, and qualify (and, where necessary, alias) only those columns you actually want returned

Comment: I have run the query in phpmyadmin and is perfectly good.

Comment: I have addet additional info that both tables have id column and I want the info from first, but with php it returns row[id] of the second

Comment: try your query in dbfiddle, they have much mire stringent rules, without knowing the result of your query, it is impossible to say what php expects. If you want to solve it on your own get rid of the * in your query and give every column a unique name

Comment: even if I specify the column names, it still gives the same result. I think the issue is that table1 has id and table2 has id, and php returns only id of table2, and I want id value of table1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both tables have a column that has the same name, so, when using `select *`, it is ambiguous to which column `id` relates to.

The only way to remove the ambiguity is to explicitly list all the columns you want to `select`, using aliases for homonyms:

```
select 
    a.id, 
    b.id b_id, -- alias for b.id
    b.item_id
    -- more columns here as needed
from firsttable a 
left join secondtable b on a.id=b.item_id 
order by a.id desc 
limit 0,10
```

This is one of the many reasons why `select *` is generally considered a bad practice in SQL.

Recommend reading: [What is the reason not to use `select *`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/321299/10676716)

Comment: @Exc: you need to *alias* the ambiguous column, as shown in my answer...

Comment: Other user had suggested alias, but to be honest I did not know what exactly is he suggesting to do, and with this example it works.